# How to set the value of input field in website in dart?

Tags: dart, post, input

I want to send a text to a input field in remote website using dart. How ever the code I have cannot be implemented in my program since it works only in web not console app.

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  final input = querySelector('.css-35zt5t') as InputElement?;
  final query = 'Hello, world!';

  if (input != null) {
    input.value = query;
  }
}
```

How to achieve the same without using InputElement??

Comment: Are you pretending to be a browser?  Are you parsing incoming fetched HTML, looking for forms?  You'll also have to parse whether it's a get or post on the return.  Simulating a browser needs a lot of steps.